# Scriptures mentioning about death of stars

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, science

Consider the following line from Mahabharata

> **I see again that the luminous bodies, large and small, which move
> in the firmament, fall down when their time comes.**
>
> [[Section 179, Mokshadharma Parva,  Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b006.htm)

It is saying that stars will eventually die.

Are there any scriptures earlier than Mahabharata do mention this fact of star death?

Comment: Are these really referring to stars, might be meteors?

Comment: @Proxy I read in translations... And are speaking about luminous bodies...

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita/d/doc229178.html) . One of the type is Tara.